# How to map the hibernate to the JSP view?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-boot

Following is a folder hierarchy in the Spring boot Hibernate project ,
[image]

This is a method in UserResource Controller

```
@GetMapping("/")
public ModelAndView home(HttpServletRequest request){
    //request.setAttribute("mode", "MODE_HOME");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    model.addObject("msg", "hello world");
    return model;
}
```

Following code also added to the application.properties file to find the correct jsp page.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:WebApp/Web/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

But this is not worked and following error is occurred.

[image]

Anyway, I tried many ways by modifying the path in the 'application.properties' file and couldn't find the right solution. Are there any steps to fire the jsp view?

Comment: Check `index.jsp` is under /WEbApp/Web.

Comment: index.jsp file exist in the /WEbApp/Web folder

Comment: According to your configuration your jsp file must be under '/WEbApp/Web' .But in the image index.jsp file under '/WebApp'

Comment: yeah. That is a another testing index.jsp file but still index.jsp file is available in the /WebApp/Web. I updated the image

Answer (score 0):

If your main class don't extends **SpringBootServletInitializer** ,try this.

```
public class SpringHibernateAssignmentApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringHibernateAssignmentApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringHibernateAssignmentApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```